# Gitk does not show HEAD of master?

Tags: git, gitk

This is on Ubuntu 14.04, `git` version 1.9.1 (same for `gitk`). I'm doing this:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/underdoeg/ofxLibRocket.git ofxLibRocket-git
Cloning into 'ofxLibRocket-git'...
remote: Counting objects: 1013, done.
remote: Total 1013 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1013
Receiving objects: 100% (1013/1013), 16.85 MiB | 326.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (631/631), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd ofxLibRocket-git
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git log -1 --decorate
commit 14360ed8fd3428aa0a2e052f6363e5daa0bf0d75 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
Merge: 06dd209 801877c
Author: Philip Whitfield <philip@undef.ch>
Date:   Fri Feb 22 03:16:37 2013 -0800

    Merge pull request #6 from neilmendoza/master

    Fixed OSX libs and example
$ gitk --all .
```

So far so good - *but*, if I run `gitk --all .` in this directory, then the commit of current HEAD is **not** indicated in the `gitk` display? This is what I get:

[image: gitk]

This is the weird thing: the only commit containing the word `OSX` shown in `gitk`, which I've selected manually:

- has the hash `801877c48390324dc7d600936306cd7c00486dcc`, unlike what `git log` shows for current head, `14360ed8fd3428aa0a2e052f6363e5daa0bf0d75`
- The `14360ed8` is the "merge pull request" by one committer, the `801877c` the pull request by another committer, for the same patch/commit, "*Fixed OSX libs and example*"
- The `14360ed8` is not listed in any commit of `gitk`
- There is no yellow dot to indicate HEAD, nor a "master" branch label, anywhere in `gitk` (and certainly not next to `801877c`).

So, why doesn't `gitk` in this case show the HEAD and the `14360ed8` commit? I have tried doing:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD
```

... but it seems to make no difference in terms of display in `gitk`... How can I get the proper display of HEAD and the master branch in this case?

---

EDIT: So, I installed `gitg` (Version 0.2.7), and it seems to make more sense visualisation-wise:

[image: gitg]

So is this a bug in `gitk`, or does `gitk` need some special setup (say, command line switches) to show this state of the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `gitk --all` without path specification gives the expected result, exactly as `gitg`
2. *It seems* that `gitk <some path>` completely ignores `--all` switch and displays the first commit which modifies a given file and doesn't collect any references. So again I wouldn't call it a bug, just a, hmm, way it's implemented. Also I should mention that specifying a file in the command line for `gitk` is a unusual thing for me.

Comment: Many thanks, @user3159253 - indeed, without the dot for current directory, `gitk --all` shows the yellow dots for HEAD etc. Re: "_specifying a file in the command line for `gitk` is a unusual thing_" - if you mean my inclusion of the current dir dot (as in `gitk --all .`), I simply saw it somewhere on this site when I looked up why I cannot see all branches in `gitk`, and I had remembered it verbatim. Cheers!