# Git shows no merge conflicts when it should

Tags: git, github, merge, branching-and-merging, git-pull

According to my understanding of merge conflicts, a merge conflict occurs when two people have changed the same file, and/or modified the same line in that file. So when I did a

`git pull origin master`

I expected a merge conflict, since the same line was different in both the versions, but it looks like git decided to overwrite my local files.

To give more information, 
I pushed my version on Github few days back. Then someone pulled it, worked with it, and pushed it back to github. Two of the files the other guy modified are of interest to me.

The first file is a config file, and the other guy changed the password in that. So when I pulled from github, the password in my local version was different from that on github. BUT, in my terminal, it said

```
Auto-merging <filename>
```

And, it overwrites my file and the password was the one set by the different guy.

The second file of interest is an HTML file written in a template engine(PUG). The other guy changed a lot of things in that file, like added a lot of css classes, removed some classes I had used, added links to css files and all. BUT when I pulled it, the terminal did not even mention that it was auto merging it, and just overwrote the entire file in my local repo and used the one from Github.

For both of the files, my question is, whether this is the expected behaviour from using git pull, or did I do anything wrong?

Below are the commands I used.

```
git checkout -b "misc"
git pull origin master
```

Also, I tried to just use fetch and then manually merge/commit it, but when I used fetch, nothing happened. The files did not change at all.

I have used git/github before, but never really worked extensively in a team using branches and pushing/pulling from github.

Comment: Was your change actually commited, or only in your working directory?

Comment: @Polygnome: You mean the changes when I pulled? Yes, they were commited and I was even asked a commit message (which by default is asked in my sublime).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Git is behaving correctly.  This is the expected (though not really "desired", in your case) result.

There's a bit at the bottom about how to work with Git to make it actually useful for you.

Besides [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102991/1256452), there's a more likely scenario.  You did this:

```
git checkout -b "misc"
git pull origin master
```

The first line is straightforward enough.  It's the second that's extra-complicated, because `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, and both of those are a little bit complicated themselves.

#### Drawing the graph (see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452))

Whenever you are working with branches in Git—and you're *always* working with branches, so this is really just "whenever you're working with Git"—it's important to keep the *commit graph* in mind.  The graph, or DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph), is always there, usually lurking just out of sight.  To see it with `git log`, use `--graph`, often with `--oneline`.  To see it with visualizers, use something like `gitk` or one of the many annoying GUIs, which give you views like those shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33619341/1256452) (this is just a randomly-chosen question on stackoverflow about what was seen in `gitk` vs `git-gui`).

The graph determines how merges will work, so it's very important at that time.  At other times, it mostly just lurks, out of the way but ever-present.  Almost everything in Git is oriented around *adding* commits, which adds entries to this graph.<sup>1</sup>

So, let's draw a bit of a graph, and then observe `git fetch` and `git merge` in action.

Here's a graph of a repository with nothing but a `master` branch, with four commits on it:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

The `master` branch "points to" the *tip-most* commit.  In this graph, with newer commits at the right, that's the right-most commit.

Each commit also points backwards, to its *parent* commit.  That is, the lines in `o--o--o` really should be arrows: `o <- o <- o`.  But these arrows all point backwards, which is annoying and mostly useless to humans, so it's nicer to just draw them as lines.  The thing is that these backwards arrows are *how* Git finds earlier commits, because branch names *only* point to the tip-most commit!

Git also has the name `HEAD`, which is a symbol for the "current commit".  The way HEAD normally works is that it actually contains the branch name, and the branch name then points to the tip commit.  We can draw this with a separate arrow:

```
                  HEAD
                   |
                   v
o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

but that takes too much room, so I usually use this:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Git will discover that `HEAD` is "attached to" (contains the name) `master`, then follow the backwards arrow from `master` to the tip commit.

> Hint: use `git log --decorate` to show branch names and `HEAD`.  It's particularly good with `--oneline --graph`: think of this as a friendly dog: *Decorate, Oneline, Graph*.  In Git 2.1 and later, `--decorate` happens automatically, so you don't have to turn it on yourself most of the time.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452) to [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).
>
> Note that `git log --decorate` prints the decoration as `HEAD -> master` when `HEAD` points to `master`.  When `HEAD` points directly to a commit, Git calls this a *detached HEAD*, and you might see `HEAD, master` instead.  This formatting trick was new in Git 2.4: before that, it just showed `HEAD, master` for both detached HEAD mode, and non-detached-HEAD mode, for this case.  In any case, I call "non-detached" an *attached HEAD*, and I think `master (HEAD)` shows this attachment pretty well.)

Now, the `git checkout -b misc` step creates a new branch name.  By default, this new branch name points to the current (HEAD) commit, so now we have:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master, misc (HEAD)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, you can never *change* a commit.  Things that seem to change a commit, really work by adding a *new* commit, that resembles the old one, and then they cover up the old one and show you the new one instead.  This makes it *look like* the commit has changed, but it hasn't.  You also can't *remove* commits, or at least, not directly: all you can do is make them *unreachable*, from branch and tag names and the like.  Once a commit is unreachable, Git's maintenance "garbage collector" *eventually* removes them.  Making `git gc` remove them *now* can be difficult.  Git tries really hard to let you get your commits back, even if you want them gone.

But, all of this applies only to *commits*, hence the rule of thumb: "commit early and often".  Anything you have actually committed, Git will try to let you retrieve again later, usually for up to 30 or 90 days.

---

#### `git fetch`

What `git fetch` does can be summarized as:

- call up another Git;
- ask it which commits *it* has; and
- collect those commits, plus whatever else is required to make those commits sensible, and add them to your repository.

In this way, Git is like [The Borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)).  But instead of: "We are the Borg.  We will add your biological and technological distinctiveness to our own," Git says "I am the Git. Your technologically-distinctive commits will be added to my own!"

So, let's see what happens when you `git fetch origin`.  You have this:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- master, misc (HEAD)
```

They have this, which has several extra commits on their `master` (and we don't care about *their* HEAD now):

```
o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- master
```

Your Git *renames* their master, calling it `origin/master` on your own end, so that you can keep them straight.  Their two new commits are added to your repository, all Borg-like.  Those new commits point back to the existing four commits, with the usual backwards arrows, but now it takes more room to draw the graph:

```
o--o--o--o     <-- master, misc (HEAD)
          \
           o--o   <-- origin/master
```

Note that none of *your* branches are changed.  Only the `origin` ones change.  Your Git adds their technological uniqueness,<sup>2</sup> and re-points *your* `origin/master` to keep track of "where `master` was on `origin` the last time I checked."

---

<sup>2</sup>This is where those big ugly SHA-1 IDs come in.  The hashes are *how* Git can tell which commits are unique to which repository.  The key is that the same *commit* always makes the same *hash ID*, so if *their* Git has commit `12ab9fc7...`, and *your* Git has commit `12ab9fc7...`, your Git already has their commit, and vice versa.  The mathematics behind all this is rather deep and beautiful.

---

#### `git merge`

The second half of `git pull` is to run `git merge`.  It runs the equivalent<sup>3</sup> of `git merge origin/master`.  The `git merge` command starts by finding the *merge base*, and this is where the graph suddenly really matters.

The *merge base* between two commits is, loosely speaking, "the point in the graph where the lines all come back together."  Usually the two commits are two branch-tips, pointed-to by two branch *names*.  A typical, and nicely obvious, case occurs with this:

```
           o--o      <-- branch1 (HEAD)
          /
o--o--o--*
          \
           o--o--o   <-- branch2
```

What `git merge` does is to locate the nearest common-ancestor commit, which I've drawn as `*` instead of just `o` here.  That's the *merge base*.  It's simply the point from which the two branches "fork off".

The *goal* of `git merge` is to find out what "you" have changed—what you've done in `branch1` since commit `*`—and what "they" have changed, i.e., what has changed in `branch2` since commit `*`.  To get those changes, Git runs two `git diff` commands.

The same applies even if we draw the commits like this:

```
o--o--o--*--o--o     <-- branch1 (HEAD)
          \
           o--o--o   <-- branch2
```

This is the same *graph*, so it's the same *merge*.  Git compares commit `*` against the tip of `branch1` ("what's changed in our two commits?"), and commit `*` against the tip of `branch2` ("what's changed in their three commits?").  Then Git does its best to *combine* those changes, and makes a new *merge* commit from the result.  The exact details of all this combining-and-committing don't matter yet, because we don't have a graph like that.

What *we* have is this:

```
o--o--o--*        <-- master, misc (HEAD)
          \
           o--o   <-- origin/master
```

Note that I've kept the `*` notion here.  That's because `git merge` still finds the merge base.  The problem here is that the merge base *is* the branch tip: the name `misc` points directly to commit `*`.

If Git were to do `git diff <commit-*> <commit-*>`, the diff would obviously be empty.  Commit `*` is the same as commit `*`.  So how can we merge these?

Git's answer is: we don't merge at all.  We do what Git calls a *fast forward*.  Note that although the internal commit arrows all point backwards, if we just imagine them pointing forwards instead, it's now easy to take the `misc` branch-label and *slide it forward*, going down along the dog-leg and then to the right.  The result looks like this:

```
o--o--o--o        <-- master
          \
           o--o   <-- origin/master, misc (HEAD)
```

So now our config file is the one in the `HEAD` commit, which is the tip-most commit of `misc`, which is the same commit as `origin/master`.

In other words, we lost *our* changes to the config file, as they were overridden by *their* changes to the config file.

---

<sup>3</sup>The details of why it doesn't actually use `git merge origin/master` are mostly irrelevant here, but have a lot to do with history.  In the old days of Git, before version 1.8.4, some `git fetch origin`s never actually bothered to update `origin/master`.  This was a bad design decision, and in all modern Git versions, `git fetch` *does* update it.

---

#### Would doing a "real merge" instead of a fast-forward help?

If we go back to our original setup (and drop the name `master` since it's in the way):

```
o--o--o--*        <-- misc (HEAD)
          \
           o--o   <-- origin/master
```

we could, instead of letting `git pull` run `git merge`, run our own `git merge --no-ff origin/master`, to merge origin/master but *not* allow Git to do a fast-forward.  Would this help?

Alas, no.  Remember that the *goal* of a merge is to *combine* all the changes since the merge-base.  So Git will run two diffs:

```
git diff <commit-*> <commit-*>     # this diff is empty
git diff <commit-*> origin/master  # this is "what they changed"
```

Git will then combine our changes (none) with their changes, and make a new merge commit:

```
o--o--o--o------o   <-- misc (HEAD)
          \    /
           o--o   <-- origin/master
```

We have a different *graph* (it's sort of a soup ladle or [Big Dipper](http://www.constellations-and-backyard-stargazing.com/big-dipper-constellation.html)), but we took their changes, including the password change, while keeping nothing of ours (we had no changes since the merge base).

#### Making merge be useful

What we need is to make sure "our" changes—they have to *be* our changes, in Git's eyes—"look different" from "their" changes.  That means we need Git to choose a *different* merge base.

The merge base is, as I said above, the point at which our commits and their commits begin to diverge.  That means we need to make our own branch, and make sure we don't "fast forward" too much, or perhaps even at all.

So, we probably *do* want to avoid `git pull`.<sup>4</sup>  We also may want to pick an earlier point at which we make our own branch.  We want our graph's branch to maintain its own distinctiveness, as it were, from theirs.  I've given a few of these commits letter-names so that I can talk about them:

```
     A-----B      <-- misc (HEAD)
    /     /
o--o--o--o        <-- master
          \
           o--C   <-- origin/master
```

In commit `A`, we change the config file to have a different password.  Then we `git merge` (not fast-forward) the tip of `master` to pick up new stuff, without letting the password change.  This step may be very manual, or totally automatic, but once it's committed, we're done: commits are permanent; they can't be changed.<sup>5</sup>

Now we can allow `master` to "fast forward" as usual:

```
     A-----B      <-- misc (HEAD)
    /     /
o--o--o--*--o--C   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now, when we `git merge origin/master` or `git merge master`,<sup>6</sup> the merge base will be the commit I've marked `*`.  If we didn't change the password from `*` to `B`, and they changed it from `*` to `C`, we'll pick up their change—but they should no longer *need* to change it, because we never send them commits `A` and `B`; we keep those to ourselves.  So there should be no change to the password from `*` to `C`, and we'll keep our changed password when we make our new merge:

```
     A-----B-----D   <-- misc (HEAD)
    /     /     /
o--o--o--o--o--C     <-- master, origin/master
```

Later, we'll pick up even more commits, merge (fast forward) them into `master`, and be ready to merge again:

```
     A-----B-----D   <-- misc (HEAD)
    /     /     /
o--o--o--o--o--C--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
```

This time, the merge base will be commit `C`—it's the closest one that is on both `misc` and their branch—and Git will diff `C` vs `origin/master`.  Presumably, they *still* won't have changed the password, because we still didn't give them commit `D`.

---

<sup>4</sup>I avoid `git pull` as much as possible, but depending on how you go about this, you may be able to use it anyway, especially for `master`.

<sup>5</sup>We make any ordinary new commit by moving the branch label to the new commit: remember that branch names just point to the tip-most commit.  We just make a new tip commit, with its parent being the previous tip-most commit, and re-point the label, moving forward one step.  But look what happens when we make a new commit that points *further back*, not just to the old tip commit, for its parent.  Now we "rewrite history" by hiding some previous commits.  (Try drawing this graph.)  This is how both `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` work.

<sup>6</sup>Note that these *do the same thing*, as the tip of `master` and the tip of `origin/master` are the *same commit*.  The one difference is that the default commit message will change: one will say "merge master" and the other will say "merge origin/master".  (There's some fiddly stuff in Git's commit message formatting that treats `master` differently from everything else, too, but we can ignore that.  It's just a historical artifact.)

---

#### One final note: configs and passwords in commits = bad

Because commits *are* so permanent, it's generally a *very* bad idea to put passwords into them.  Anyone with access to your repository can look through historical commits and find the passwords.

Configuration files, too, generally shouldn't be committed at all, though here there's no real *security* issue.  Instead, it's a matter of the very problem you have run into: everyone needs a different configuration.  Committing yours to a shared repository makes no sense.  If it's a *private* repository, that makes somewhat more sense, and if it's a private *branch* it's OK (if still sub-optimal in most cases).

It's pretty common to want some sort of *sample* configuration, or a default initial configuration.  *These* should indeed be in commits.  The trick is to make sure that the sample, or default initial, configuration is separate from the "live" configuration.  For instance, with some systems, you'd include:

```
config.default
```

and have a little bit of code, such as:

```
[ -f .config ] || cp config.default .config
```

to set up the default configuration as the `.config` file on the first run.  Then with `.config` in `.gitignore`, it won't ever get put *into* the repository, so it will never be in any commits and you won't have this issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It is pretty clear to me now what git did and why.  Although when I did just a git fetch, nothing happened in my repo, but the git pull worked. Do you know what could be the reason?

About the configs and passwords in commit, I know it is a bad idea, but this is a final project for a course and hence the professor might want to see it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk: oops, yes. (I've changed my usual StackOverflow graph-drawing since then though)

Answer (score 6):

Check your `.git/config` in repository, git would also choose other guy's changes if the config contained the following:

```
[branch "master"]
    mergeoptions = --strategy-option theirs
```

If this is true, remove `mergeoptions` line.

From [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> **recursive**
>
> ...This is the default merge strategy when pulling or
>   merging one branch. The recursive strategy can take the following options:
>
> *ours* This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly
>   by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not
>   conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary
>   file, the entire contents are taken from our side.
>
> ...
>
> *theirs* This is the opposite of ours.

Comment: This is a possibility, but it seems unlikely.  Upvoted anyway since it's an obscure case that people *will* forget. :-)