# git merge does not change anything while git log shows merge history

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am working on Branch A while other dev working on Branch B.

I wanted to pull everything in Branch B to Branch A. I have cloned both branches in my local.

What I did upon reading one of the SO post:

```
git checkout branch B
git pull 
git checkout branch A
git merge branch B
```

And the merge message were following:

```
Auto-merging fileBar
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .../file               | 92 ++++++++++++++++++----
 file1     |  9 ++-
 .../file2          |  2 +-
 .../file3                       |  6 +-
 .../file4                     |  4 +-
 .../file5              |  2 +-
 file6   |  2 +-
 .../file7               |  4 +-
 8 files changed, 91 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)
```

However, i was expect to solve some merge conflict, i was surprised that git does not yell at me for this.

So what I did after this point:

```
git status
```

It shows that nothing in my local is changed, weird?

then i did:

```
git log
```

which shows:

```
Author: me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 18 14:47:00 2019 -0400

Merge branch 'B' into A
```

I also tried to pull branch B while on branch A:

```
git pull origin branchB
```

but it says it is update to date:

```
From https://github.com/myGit/myRepo
 * branch              BranchB -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

However, when I log on to Git, those repos are clearly not the same on remote.

At this point, I am confused. what happened here? How do I pull branch B into branch A?

Update: I just found out that when i did:

```
git checkout branch B
git pull
```

The new changes were not actually pulled. when I did git pull, it says it is already up to date, while it is clearly not.  My local still have the old  version of branch B. How? I am confused by everything at this point

What I have tried:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/BranchB
```

None of these worked

Comment: are you positive the other Dev "pushed" his changes to branch B on the server?

Comment: @JeffR.Yeah, because when I lok at git, i do see he commited the changes.  One thing worth mentioning is that, I pulled my branch through --single-branch command, if that's relevant

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you *cloned* with `--single-branch` (pull has no such option). That is somewhat relevant—a single-branch clone is deliberately limited (some might say "crippled" but that's probably too strong). If you undo the single-branch-ness the repository will be much better behaved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything worked properly.

```
git checkout branch B
git pull 
git checkout branch A
git merge branch B
```

After you ran the above, `A` was merged with `B` (which you confirmed with `git log` and `git pull origin branchB`).

[`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) correctly showed no staged/unstaged changes in the working tree, all of the changes get committed with the merge.

The fact that there were no conflicts is a bit [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097125/git-shows-no-merge-conflicts-when-it-should). You may want to review methods for dealing with [branches that depend on each other](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351727/working-on-a-branch-with-a-dependence-on-another-branch-that-is-being-reviewed). The simplest way to use branches, is to work on isolated "feature branches" that don't depend on one another. You merge the branches into `master` when they're ready, and then you pull `master` into the other branches to keep them up to date.

The remote branches (on GitHub) won't be updated until you `git push`, which it doesn't seem like you've done.

Additionally, it seems like you've now reset `A` to be the same as `B` (`git reset --hard origin/BranchB`) and potentially lost any work you've done on `A`. To remedy this, use [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to see a history of your recent actions, and then do `git reset --hard $REFLOG_HASH` where the HASH is the numbers to the left of the action where you did the merge - so that you can `reset` your working tree to that point in history. And then you can use `git push` to update the remote.